# Linux: access previously used Directory

Tags: linux, directory, environment-variables, expansion

I'm hoping this is a simple question. Here's a scenario: I have just finished running this command.

`ls -l /usr/bin /bin` (or something with a directory param involved). I would now like to `cd` into one of my most recently accessed directories ( i.e. either `\usr\bin` or `\bin`).

Is there an environment variable that I could use to accomplish this?

My searches revealed to me a tantalizing `$OLDPWD`, but when I tried `echo $OLDPWD`, I did not get the result that I was expecting.

Of course, there are two directories in my `ls -l` example, which complicates the issue. But I was thinking that the system may store the most recently accessed directories in an array that could be called via expansion or something else.
Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: This is more on topic at http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com but, `cd -` will return you to the immediately previous directory you had been in, and then check the shell's man page for `pushd` and `popd` to store directories on a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!$` is replaced by the last argument of the previous command line, so executing `cd !$` after the `ls` command above will execute `cd /bin`.

I don't know of an easy way to refer to the next-to-last argument, but you can refer to arguments by index with the syntax `!:n`, where *n* is the argument number. After the above `ls` command, `cd !:2` will execute `cd /usr/bin`.

For more information, look up [History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) in the bash man page or search for "bash history expansion" online.

Comment: Thank you. History expansion can also be accomplished without the colon; e.g., `!n` I am testing this now in my CYGWIN terminal and it functions. Interestingly enough, `!:n` doesn't work. It could just be an idiosyncrasy of CYGWIN  (there are a few). But I am sure that the `!n` notation works on my Ubuntu box at home as well. Either way, your answer is what I was looking for!

Comment: That's odd. I just tested it in bash 3.2.25 on Linux and bash 4.3.39 on Cygwin, and it worked in both. `!2` should refer to the second whole command line in your history, not the second parameter from the previous command. You can use the `history` command to see what command is associated with which number for the `!n` syntax.

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't assume you are using bash. Are you in a different shell?